# In Qt Creator, right-align a button in a window (preferably without nesting in layout widgets)

Tags: qt, user-interface, qt-creator

I created a brand new desktop project.

In the designer, in the included mainwindow.ui, I dragged in a push button.

When I run the app and resize the window by dragging around the bottom-right corner, the button does not move. It's locked to the top-left corner.

Pretty standard default behavior in all gui tools/kits.

But when I try to lock the button to the bottom and right edges of the window, nothing I've found in the properties editor seems to work.  Obviously this is possible and I'm just missing something.

What's the trick here? -- keeping in mind that I'd prefer not to have to nest the button in another container to do it (i.e: window/layoutwidget/button). If that's the only way, fine, but if there's a way to do it without bringing in extra widgets then I'd be more interested in that.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use layouts, then I think you're stuck with overriding `resizeEvent(QResizeEvent *event)` and moving the button manually.

```
void MainWindow::resizeEvent(QResizeEvent *ev)
{
    if(this->isVisible()) {
        QRect buttonGeo = ui->pushButton->geometry();
        buttonGeo.translate(ev->size().width() -ev->oldSize().width(),
                            ev->size().height()-ev->oldSize().height());
        ui->pushButton->setGeometry(buttonGeo);
    }
}
```

This moves (translates) the button based on how much the size of the window has changed. To protect against the initial "oldSize" of the window not being set, I added a check against "isVisible" of the MainWindow.

Anchoring is trivial in QML, though, with the `anchor.bottom/anchor.right` properties.

It looks like you *can* do anchoring layouts in non-QML, but you need to use a `QGraphicsScene + QGraphicsAnchorLayout` (https://doc.qt.io/qt-6.4/qtwidgets-graphicsview-anchorlayout-example.html).

If you use regular layouts: To prevent the button from resizing, set the maximum width of the button and/or set the stretch factors of the layout to 1,0 (where 0 is the column with the button). Both can be done in Designer.

Comment: Did you test that `resizeEvent`? and could you explain how it works? which corner is the button supposed to be locked on?